# Calculate Protractor Angle in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, angle

I am trying to create a protractor in windows phone 7 using silverlight framework and I am stuck in getting the protractor needle to rotate.

I am using rotate transform and specifying the angle value to the transform name in the code behind.

I need a perfect angle calculation and currently the protractor needle is not rotating as required.

Any help would be truly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is it rotating at all or is it the wrong rotation? Can we see some code?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var rotateTransform = (RotateTransform)yourControl.RenderTransform;
rotateTransform.Angle = 90.0f;
```

I wrote this out of top of my head, but this is general rule how you should do this in code behind... the other thing is - make sure you are getting some values via Debug.WriteLine() and then watch Output in VS.